# Change a Text dynamically using PointerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As I'm currently developing a Unity Engine based Game right now I need a PointerEnter EventTrigger to change my Text dynamically. Specifically:

If the user hovers with the Mouse in the MainMenu over a Text, I want an indicator on which Option he is pointing at. 
So from `Options` the Text should turn to `▶ Options`.

What I did is the following:

```
Text text;
string ContinueText = "▶ Continue";

void Awake()
{
    // Set up the reference.
     text = GetComponent<Text>();
}
    public void Test()
{
    text.text = ContinueText;
}
```

But if I hover over the Text I get

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

pointing at `text.text = ContinueText;`

So I searched around the Web and found that `void Update()` is sometimes called before *Awake()*, the Error stays the same anyway. The Canvas-Text is named "Text_Options", in case you need that.

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: The first `Update` of an object is always called after `Awake()`. Is the script on the text object? `GetComponent` only works if that component is on the same object as the script.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes, the Script is on the specific Text I want to Change. So the Script is attached to a GameObject, which is attached to the EventTrigger.

Comment: You have `using UnityEngine.UI;` in the script? (I guess so otherwise you should have different errors.)

Comment: @GunnarB. Your guess is right :) If you are running out of ideas, we may meet in TeamViewer, sou you can take a look on my Code?

Comment: Added an answer, maybe you can figure out what you did wrong from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an working example.

A canvas with an empty gameobject (has a vertical layout group, but thats not relevant) that is a container for two text objects.
[image]
[image]

I've added two event triggers each, OnPointerEnter and OnPointerExit. Both text objects have my script `HoverText` on them:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HoverText : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text text;
    public string content = "Text A";
    public string contentHighlighted = "▶ Text A";

    void Awake()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        text.text = content;
    }

    public void Highlight()
    {
        text.text = contentHighlighted;
    }

    public void UnHighlight()
    {
        text.text = content;
    }
}
```

`Text_A` has itself as gameobject for it's both event triggers and `Text_B` itself respectively. The public strings for the two different text contents are set via inspector (default value from script is actually matching `Text_A` in my example).

That's it, works fine.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much! :)